# ¿Cómo hacer temporizador en JSP?

Tags: jsp

Saludos a Todos, necesito ayuda...Estoy empezando con JSP aunque ya tengo conocimientos de Java y tengo que crear un temporizador en JSP que vaya de 10 a 0 y cuando llegue al final cerrar la aplicación.

El problema es que :

```
Timer timer = new Timer (tiempoEnMilisegundos, new ActionListener () 
{ 
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    { 
        // Aquí el código que queramos ejecutar.
     } 
});
```

Eso siempre lo usé en JAVA y no dio problemas,**ahora el NetBeans se queja porque el tiempo en Milisegundos no lo acepta**...

He probado con

```
      int tempo= 10 ;
      session.setAttribute("tiempo", tempo);
      TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() { 

        public void run() {
            int chapuza;
            do{
              chapuza = (int)session.getAttribute("tiempo");
              chapuza --;
              session.setAttribute("tiempo", chapuza);
            }while(chapuza > 0);

        } 
         }; 
         timerTask.run();
```

Esta es otra cosa que se me ha ocurrido, el timerAsk no tengo que meterle tiempo y tampoco le puedo pasar argumentos, así que trabajo con la variable de session 
Pero tampoco me vale....

Ya no sé me ocurre nada para tener un temporizador en JSP y sobre que se cierre la aplicación o la ventana al cliente tampoco sé como hacerlo
:'(

Gracias

Pd : No puedo usar Javascript ni otro lenguaje, Only JSP.
Que vaya mostrando el tiempo, mientras el usuario interactua, por eso necesito un hilo como el Timer ...

Comment: `Only JSP. Que vaya mostrando el tiempo, mientras el usuario interactua, por eso necesito un hilo como el Timer` Creo que estás confundido. El JSP no es interactivo. Le haces una petición HTTP, te devuelve HTML que se muestra en el navegador. El `Timer` no "mostrará" nada.

Comment: Gracias por responder pero entonces cómo puedo hacer un temporizador en el servidor, que lo vaya viendo el cliente y que el cliente pueda de mientras hacer cosas ?

Es decir, sería se abre la ventana del cliente y automáticamente y constantemente se envía una petición al servidor que te "devuelve constamente una cuenta atrás.
El servidor solo tiene que tener un temporizador.

Pero no sé como ponérselo...

Comment: Polling (de página completa, de frame o Ajax) o WebSockets. Lo que más se ajusta a una comunicación bidireccional serían WebSockets, pero puede ser más complicado.

Comment: Se hacía con un bucle for y luego un out.flush para que mostrara por pantalla como si fuera un temporizador.